# Better way to bind generic List to DomainUpDown control (text spin control)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I have been trying to find out how to bind data to a
 
`System.Windows.Forms.DomainUpDown()` control.

Currently I have only come up with:

```
        private void Init()
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            list = get4000Strings(); //4000 items

            foreach (string item in list)
            {
                domainUpDown1.Items.Add(item); 
            }

        }

        private List<string> get4000Strings()
        {
            List<string> l = new List<string>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 4000; i++)
            {
                l.Add(i.ToString());
            }
            return l;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DomainUpDown.Items` collection has an `AddRange()` method that takes an `ICollection` (implemented by `List<T>`), so you could just do

```
private void Init() {
  List<string> list = new List<string>();
  list = get4000Strings(); //4000 items
  domainUpDown1.Items.Clear();
  domainUpDown1.Items.AddRange(list);
}
```

However, if you have that much items to show, I would suggest you use a `ComboBox` having `DropDownStyle` set to `DropDownList`.
It will allow you to databind directly to the list (e.g. `comboBox1.DataSource = list;`), especially if the list changes often, as you won't have to refill the ComboBox each time, just change the datasource...